# Запуск приложения по ссылке/кнопке. CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Как сделать чтобы по нажатию кнопки/ссылки предлагалось или автономно запустить предложение в CefSharp? В webBrowser это сделать легко, просто нажать на кнопку. В CefSharp у меня появились проблемы, он не запускает и не предлагает запустить приложение. Как заставить его запускать хоть как-то запускать приложения?

[image: Запуск Приложения]

Comment: Поискал немного, наткнулся на [это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31241240) и мне кажется это вполне годный вариант решения задачи.

Comment: Годный, но не для меня. Даже не знаю как описать это, но попробую. Допустим я нажал на кнопку "Launch App" и генерируется уникальная ссылка с нужной информацией и запускается приложение. Это приложение считывает ссылку и делает нужные операции. Так же работает без известная игра "Roblox" (Не нашёл лучше примера:))

Comment: И почему вариант не годится?

Comment: Потому-что если посмотреть код элемента страницы, то можно увидеть уникальные параметры для запуска приложения. А как их считывать и запустить приложение с такими параметрами, для меня вопрос. https://imgur.com/WZgoiNU